# Please add language specific selective copy to code fragments

Tags: feature-request, editor

If the poster has copied from the user interface, especially in interactive languages such as [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) lines entered by the user will start with either `>>>` or `...` while lines of responses and error messages will not.

Wouldn't it be possible for a copy mechanism to only copy lines that started with the prompt and skip any lines that didn't plus strip the known prompt characters out of the copied code?

This would greatly simplify copying code **from** questions & answers to try the code out and work on the solution.

Obviously such changes should only be applied when copying **from** examples/answers rather than when copying **into** them.

For example, if the user posts:

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01)
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print 2,
2
>>> print fred
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'fred' is not defined
>>> print fred()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'fred' is not defined
>>> def fred():
...    return (27)
...
>>> print fred()
27
>>>
```

And I select and paste it I would like it to paste as:

```
print 2,
print fred
print fred()
def fred():
   return (27)

print fred()
```

Comment: But if I copy code I copied it that way because I want it to look that way. If you show someone what code will look like on the interpreter then they know exactly what you're doing.... which is helpful for newer people. You've also missed the return value and exceptions, which is not something helpful to exclude.

Comment: I am talking about copying __from__ the site __not__ to it.  Question clarified.

Comment: If I copy code I want it to look exactly the same when pasted. If the real problem is users posting poorly formatted code, then we should educate them about it. Sites that modify what you're copying (through use of invisible text or Javascript) are among the worst on the Internet, to be honest.

Comment: So you enjoy going through a pasted example and removing all the >>> and ... at the start of every line!

Comment: I wouldn't particularly enjoy it, but I definitely wouldn't enjoy a site messing with the text I copy from it. The question is: Does this happen so often that it warrants the implementation of the feature you request? I could imagine that it'd take quite a bit of time to figure out all the specifics, and even then we'd just be talking about one implementation of a Python interpreter.

Comment: Hint: `s/>>> //` removes the start of the line just fine.

Comment: As *why not* could be a interesting thread (I think this is one of the goal of *meta-SO*), please stop downvote this and explain your point of vue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don't change a working solution

Adding such kind of feature may have some unpredictable *border effects*. As my opinion is that all work fine now, and the formating operation for publishing on SO stay quite simple and efficient.

Please don't touch!

### Build your own workaround solutions

#### `sed` on the fly

You could even filter both ouptut of your interpreter by `sed` on the fly,

Running directly you interpreter by:

```
python 2>&1| sed -ue 's/^\(\(>\|\.\)\2\2 \)*//'
```

or

```
python 2>&1| sed -ue 's/^\(>>> \|\.\.\. \)*//'
```

than hit your sample

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
print 3,
3
print fred
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'fred' is not defined
print fred()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'fred' is not defined
def fred():
    return(31)

print fred()
31
exit()
```

this could be improved.

#### `script` output re-formated

Another solution may use tools like `script` for storing whole operation, than a little script could be used to re-format stored *scriptfiles*.

```
script -c python /tmp/python;sed 's/^\(\.\|>\)\1\1 //;s/^/    /' /tmp/python
```

Offer a nice way for this:

```
Script started on Sun Jul 28 11:13:04 2013
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
print 4
4
print fred
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'fred' is not defined
print fred()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'fred' is not defined
def fred():
    return (32)

print fred()
32
exit()

Script done on Sun Jul 28 11:13:48 2013
```

### My own solution for editing [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) answers

I just run any *x-terminal* with exactly **84** columns, run a inner `bash`
I could quit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and return to higher session without closing window:

```
bash
exec 1> >(sed -ue 's/^/    /;
           :a;
           s/^\(\(.\{84\}\n\)*.\{84\}\)\([^\n]\{5\}\)/\1\n    \3/;
           ta') ;PS1='    ';PROMPT_COMMAND='sleep .2'
```

So I could run command, having output formatted, ready to cut'n'paste.

**Bug:** Don't run interactives commandes like `less` or `man` in this!

Comment: Added [tag:bash] solution

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want lines that start with ">>> " and "... " but with those characters removed.

One of many ways to do this: you can use **sed** in **bash** / **dash** (or any shell that supports heredocs) to format the Python console code you copied

```
sed -n 's/^>>> //p; s/^\.\.\. //p' <<'EOI'
... copied code here ...
EOI
```

then you can copy the output of this command to Python interpreter.